# My Dracaena Fragrans Might Be Dying PLEASE help

Tags: houseplants, leaves, dracaena

**2/15, I did this:**

I finally built up the nerve to chop my corn plant and propagate it

Here's the damage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhaPm.jpg

I am praying I did this right. I followed a video that showed how one guy did it successfully, and I'm hoping it will go that well for me. I dabbed root hormone on the bottom of the cut-off stalks and placed two in dirt, and the rest are in water (so the root hormone probably doesn't matter, but still). I am hoping at least one of these methods works!

The first pic is the original plant, which I hate to see all cut, but I am hoping it's ok.

Is it in the right light? I am trying to find the best spots for them, whether that be indoor or outdoors I don't know yet. The temperature, as far as I know, is ok.

**2/23 UPDATE**

The original stalk + a cutting is starting to yellow...PLEASE HELP!!

It might be sun-scorched...I moved it inside for that reason and humidity. Should I spray it with a mister for humidity?

I am so worried...I think I may be overwatering...I will definitely stop & I also will use bottled water in case it's a fluoride issue.

Here's a leaf I pulled off: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmR5v.jpg

The other stalk I moved seems fine, but it's also titled as hell. **I am so scared I killed it by propagating/cutting it...Help!**

Comment: I have also propagated my more contrasting version Lemon Lime dracaena. I just cut the stem and removed some lower leaves and placed it in damp soil. They haven't gone yellow till now. Almost more than a week. I think you should not keep any plant propagation in direct sun. And there are too many leaves in the cutting. So maybe your plant will get more brown leaves. Make sure the soil ain't too wet or dry. I am not sure about the right way, maybe some expert can help. I think humidity should be good and misting might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything else, I ask that you:

- please don’t panic;
- exercise patience.

Beyond that, I provide the following advice...

As a general rule, all cuttings, in particular those of subtropical or tropical plants (which include the smaller plants of Dracena sp.) should remain in full shade in the weeks immediately following attempts to propagate through slips and cuttings. Only once your young cuttings have established, would I carefully and under a close eye, move them progressively into sunnier positions.

I understand that Dracena sp. are, apart from the tree sized plants in the genus, an understory plant from tropical rainforests, so would generally advise (depending on your climate and latitude) only filtered light or morning sun for even a mature plant.

Dracena slips can take a very long time to establish enough new roots to support growth above ground. Please do not disturb the slips you’ve cut, as that may cause them to abort their current efforts and they may not have the energy to try again.

Dracena sp. are often a plant that is killed with kindness. They need water and nutrient during their growing season (which will change depending on your climate) and **thrive on neglect at all other times**.

I struck my Dracena marginata tricolour about three years ago. All the leaves fell off and the original trunk pieces / slips perished (shrivelled and died), but with some enforced patience, over nine months later, a new shoot appeared from the remains of two of the three cuttings. Only one of those two survived, however now I am the proud owner of a still rather small plant I grew myself.

At the end of our last winter, when we suffer our coldest weather, my Dracena plant almost perished. I placed it in a protected position where it enjoyed morning sun and as little wind as possible with only minimal water. It recovered during our hot humid summer and is now thriving.

Your parent plant will most likely recover but, depending on your climate and whether you’re in the northern or southern hemisphere, it may take six to twelve months before new shoots and leaves appear.

In the meantime, please refer to my opening comments and water the plant as you normally would.

I hope these experiences help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your plant looks as if it is struggling against something, and all you can do is experiment to find out what that factor is. You have done all the right things and now need to just hold on and hope for the best. At the very least you are gaining experience.

The pot has lots of soil but the plant is a bit small compared to its root volume available. It might be very instructive to turn the plant out of its pot to examine the roots but I think that might end up a bit of a mess  since there might not be enough root to bind the soil into a block, so I won't recommend that unless you feel really adventurous one day. Turn the pot onto its side on a plastic surface and tease the pot away from the roots until you can see roots. Look for anything odd like bugs or very wet clumps of soil. Take a photo or two for comparison in a few weeks time.